# jQuery tooltip stuck on left side of page, unresponsive to placement/position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-tooltip, jquery-ui-tooltip

I have a jQuery tooltip that should hover over my table header. It shows up on the far left side of my screen, with no formatting - just black text. I have tried using placement and position jquery attributes to no avail. Code:

```
.container
.row
    .col-sm-12
        %ol.breadcrumb
            %li
                = link_to 'Dashboard', dashboard_index_path
            %li
                = link_to 'Phase 3', phase_path( 3 )
            %li
                = link_to 'Step 1', phase_step_path( @phase, @step )
            %li
                Activity 3: Treatment Adaptations Table
.row
    .col-sm-12
        %h1
            Activity 3: Treatment Adaptations Table


        %p
            To review instructions, see
            = link_to 'Phase 3 Step 1 guide', phase_step_path( @phase, @step )
    %table.table.table-bordered 
        %thead
            %th{"data-toggle" => "tooltip", "title" => "tooltip"}
                Specify reason(s) for the adaptation
            %th{"data-toggle" => "tooltip", "title" => "tooltip"}
                Identify any specific concerns about the adaptation
            %th{"data-toggle" => "tooltip", "title" => "tooltip"}
                How will concerns be addressed?
            %th{"data-toggle" => "tooltip", "title" => "tooltip"}
                Specify how the adaptation will be made
            %th{"data-toggle" => "tooltip", "title" => "tooltip"}
                Who will carry out the adaptation?
```

jQuery:

```
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
  'placement': 'top'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can post a jsfiddle link, it'll be easier to get help. Your HAML file can be compiled into some html that cannot be easily produced locally (without all those variables)

Comment: It seems to work in the jsfiddle I created: http://jsfiddle.net/attgy27h/

Maybe the problem is caused by my application.html.haml file? I can see that the tooltips are being created after my wrapper and container page elements rather than within.

Comment: That's hard to guess :) But here is how I would debug it:
1. pass in the "trigger": "click" option so the tooltip stay on screen;
2. The tooltip is absolutely positioned, so check it against its 'positioned' parent (nodes with relative/absolute position)
3. the background color is defined by bootstrap:
`code
    .tooltip-inner {
      max-width: 200px;
      padding: 3px 8px;
      color: #fff;
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      background-color: #000;
      border-radius: 4px;
    }
`
Good luck.